# UWP - Microsoft SimpleInk sample app crashes after clicking the Erase All Ink menu

Tags: uwp, inkcanvas

Using the SimpleInk sample app from the Microsoft windows universal sample master from github.

After going in the Scenario 1 in the Erase All Ink command few thing the app crash, has any experience this and does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, did you modify the code of the official sample? If not, can you please list the steps which can help us to reproduce this issue?

Comment: No code modification.  Steps: 1) select Scenario 1, 2) draw strokes, 3) select Erase All Ink, 4) select Scenario 2 then click back to Scenario 1 and repeat steps several times and app will crash.

Comment: OK, I can reproduce this issue now, by look into this further, this is a "Access violation" exception, we will keep investigate on this problem and let you know if we get any progress.